# how to make an interactive bot command in discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

**i saw another post asking the same question and it was answered and the guys said it worked, but i literally copied pasted what the guy wrote and it doesnt work, the code is this:**

```
client.on("message", async message => {

const filter = msg => msg.author.id == message.author.id;

    const options = {
        maxMatches: 1
    };

    if (message.content === ";color") {

        // request
         message.channel.send("What's your fav color?");

    // collector
    let collector = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, options);
    let answer = collector.first().content;

    // response
    await message.reply("your fav color is " + answer + "!");
  }
});
```

Anyone knows what's wrong with it or if i need to install anything?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to define client, and login. Make also sure to install discord.js.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on("message", async message => {

const filter = msg => msg.author.id == message.author.id;

    const options = {
        maxMatches: 1
    };

    if (message.content === ";color") {

        // request
         message.channel.send("What's your fav color?");

    // collector
    let collector = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, options);
    let answer = collector.first().content;

    // response
    await message.reply("your fav color is " + answer + "!");
  }
});

client.login("<your token>");
```

This would probably work, but I recommend looking up some more in-depth tutorials on setting up your first discord bot. This tutorial for example: https://learn.g2.com/how-to-make-discord-bot.

Comment: no sry man...i put the code in index just to make sure it would work..but ofc i wouldn't send the whole index code in here...so those were already defined...i have a lot of other commands dont need tutorial..just for this interactive command...